# remove string with wildcard form list

Tags: python-3.x

how can I remove an element from a list if it only contains components. Or how can I bet a wildcard?

i want remove '+03+ [ NEW INFO WILL RESOLVE TO TILL ]+' in test, wehen 'new' from skiplist match is

```
skiplist = ['new', 'aa']
test = ['+03+ [ NEW INFO WILL RESOLVE TO TILL ]+', 'aa asfa', 'bb', 'cc', 'asdkfljiopwerjasdlf']

for skip in skiplist:
    if skip in test: test.remove(skip)
    print(test)
```

the list should look like this

```
test = ['bb', 'cc', 'asdkfljiopwerjasdlf']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify the original list:

```
skiplist = ['new', 'aa']
test = ['+03+ [ NEW INFO WILL RESOLVE TO TILL ]+', 'aa asfa', 'bb', 'cc', 'asdkfljiopwerjasdlf']

for skip in skiplist:
    for item in test:
        if skip in item.lower():
            test.remove(item)

print(test)
```

If you do not want to modify the original list, just make a copy of it before you loop through it

```
def discarder(test, skiplist):
    copy = test[:]
    for skip in skiplist:
        for item in copy:
            if skip in item.lower():
                copy.remove(item)
    return copy
```

If your test is a dict:

```
skiplist = ['new', 'aa']

test = {
    1: '+03+ [ NEW INFO WILL RESOLVE TO TILL ]+',
    2: 'aa asfa',
    3: 'bb',
    4: 'cc',
    5: 'asdkfljiopwerjasdlf'
}


def discard(test, skiplist):
    my_dict = test.copy()
    for skip in skiplist:
        for i in range(1, len(test)):
            val = test.get(i)
            if skip in val.lower():
                my_dict.pop(i)
    return my_dict


filtered_vals = discard(test, skiplist)
print(filtered_vals)
```

Answer (score 0):

wiht list comprehension:

```
check(x):
    for skip in skiplist:        
        if skip in x.lower():
            return False
    else:
         return True


test = [x for x in test if check(x)]
```

with for loops:

```
for x in test:
    for skip in skippers:
        if skip.lower() in x.lower():
            test.remove(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two for loops :

```
skiplist = ['new', 'aa']
test = ['+03+ [ NEW INFO WILL RESOLVE TO TILL ]+', 'aa asfa', 'bb', 'cc', 'asdkfljiopwerjasdlf']

for t in test[:]:
    for skip in skiplist:
        if skip.lower() in t.lower():
            test.remove(t)
print(test)
```